# A tool to create a visual map of Domain Users and Groups

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a tool that can create a visual map of my domain users and the hierarchy of the groups they are in?

An automated tool/script is preferred.

This is one huge forest, and groups within groups make it even worse.

I am trying to make some order with this, and a visual map can assist here.

another option can be: How do you do it?

Answer (score 2):

While I've never actually done this, there's an MSDN article on how to do this with Visio and Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226689(office.11).aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12038

Comment: That looks so promissing. Gonna have to wait till Sunday for me to check this out. Super thanks. If it works, i'll post some exe's.

Answer (score 0):

We use a combination of Visio and abusing the helpdesk guys/interns.

As in: "Since you pissed me off by escalating a stupid user issue to me, go into Visio and update the diagram with another two dozen groups before you go home."

But there's no reason it has to be Visio and helpdesk guys; you can do it with any decent diagramming software and any supply of workers you're allowed to abuse.

Comment: As I am that "Abused guy" I think I will pass this one for now :-)  will wait for another answer.

Comment: @Saariko  Well, my condolences, but you may have to just "grin and bear it," so to speak.  I know of no such tool or scipt... so your efforts might be better spent getting promoted, or findin an intern of your own to dump this off on. :)

Comment: Said the HopelessN00b  :-)   thanks